# How to dynamically create horizontal list of buttons in NativeScript?

Tags: typescript, mvvm, data-binding, nativescript

I have started using native script and I have a little struggle with MVVM concept, especially binding. I have setup environment to work with TypeScript.

I have a HomePage where I need to create a horizontal list of buttons. However, firstly I need to fetch from server what buttons I need to show:

```
let page: Page;
let viewModel = new MainViewModel();
let fetchCategoriesUseCase: FetchCategoriesUseCase = new FetchCategoriesUseCase(new InMemoryCategoriesRepository());

export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
    page = <Page>args.object;    
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;
}

export function onMapReady() {
    console.log("Map is ready"); 
    fetchCategoriesUseCase.handle(null).then((result: IFetchCategoriesResult) => {
        viewModel.categories = result.getCategories();
    });
}
```

and `MainViewModel.ts`

```
export class MainViewModel extends Observable {
    private mMap: Observable;
    private mCategories: Category[];

    public constructor() {
        super();    

        this.mMap = fromObject({
            latitude: 42.442574,
            longitude: 19.268646,
            zoom: 13
        });
    }

    get map(): Observable {
        return this.mMap;
    }

    get categories(): Category[] {
        return this.mCategories;
    }

    set categories(categories: Category[]) {
        this.mCategories = categories;
    }
}
```

In the `main.xml` i have this:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <maps:mapView 
        left="0"
        top="0"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        latitude="{{ map.latitude }}" 
        longitude="{{ map.longitude }}" 
        zoom="{{ map.zoom }}"  
        mapReady="onMapReady"
        cameraChanged="onMapCameraChanged"/>

    <ScrollView
        left="0" 
        top="0"
        width="100%"
        orientation="horizontal">

        <Repeater items="{{ categories }}">
            <Repeater.itemsLayout>
                <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" />
            </Repeater.itemsLayout>
            <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                <Button text="{{ getName() }}"/>
            </Repeater.itemTemplate>
        </Repeater>
    </ScrollView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Thing that I notice is, when I start my application, initially list is empty (as expected), but after I ask repository for buttons in `onMapReady()` function and call `viewModel.categories = result.getCategories()`, the list is still empty.

Now if I change something in XML and save, then NativeScript CLI will sync that change with device and it will not recreate page, but just recreate view, and then since reference to `MainViewModel` object was not lost and it contains these buttons in `categories` field, it will actually show them... So as I see it the problem is that when I set property `categories`, listeners are not notified about this change, hence the view is not updated to show non-empty list of buttons... I guess I bind it wrong...

How do I solve this problem? I think it has to do with ObservableArray but I am not sure how it should be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

```
set categories(categories: Category[]) {
    this.mCategories = categories;
    this.notifyPropertyChange('categories', categories)
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer so that the OP is able to understand its purpose